# How do I resolve Access Denied message

Tags: users

I created 2 roles on my site: Buyer and Seller

I used auto assign role to allow the user choose a role on sign up.

I then created an additional profile for seller using profile 2. (The buyer is supposed to be logged in immediately he signs up)

Using rules, i tried to redirect the user who chooses the seller role to the page setup with profile 2, but it comes up with access denied, you are not authorized to access this page.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

The redirection is happening before the login is processed, hence the error. The way I'd handle this would be to do the check when the profile page is viewed, rather than during the login process. So the trigger for the action is on viewing a page, specifying the user view page and adding a condition that the user being viewed is a seller.